# ng-model not binding on ng-repeated options in select element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Somehow I seem to achieved only one way data binding when using an ng-model inside an ng-repeat.

Currently if the user makes a selection from one of the dropdowns, the model is updated. But for some reason the selects are not binding to changes in the model.

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl as c">
  <table>
      <tr ng-repeat="controller in c.data">
        <td>
          <select ng-model="controller.port" required="" class="form-control form-control-inline">
            <option value="">Choose a port</option>
            <option value="{{idx}}" ng-repeat="idx in c.pwm" ng-disabled="c.isPWMUsed(idx)">
              {{idx}} {{c.isPWMUsed(idx)? 'used' : ''}}
            </option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
  </table>
  <pre>
{{c.data | json:4}}
  </pre>
</body>
```

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    this.data = [
        {
            "port": 1
        },
        {
            "port": "2"
        },
        {
            "port": ""
        },
        {
            "port": "5"
        }
    ];
    this.pwm = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];

    this.isPWMUsed = function (n) {
        var out = false;
        n=n.toString();
        for (var i = 0; i < this.data.length; i++) {
            if (this.data[i].port === n) {
                out = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        return out;
    };

    $scope.gettypeof = function(item){
        return (typeof item);
    };
});
```

Here is a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/QlEP73aZwhjcjRGszbJb?p=preview
Notice how the default data has some ports preassigned. However they do not seem to be bound to the dropdowns properly.

-- Edit --
The reason I did not use ng-options was because I could not figure out how to disable options when they are selected. Notice the functionality adding ng-disabled="c.isPWMUsed(idx)" adds, making it so that the user cannot select an item that has been selected with one of the other dropdowns.

-- Edit 2 --
So really the question boils down to "is there a way to make two way binding work for select when options come from ng-repeat?"

Another Identical Case, Using the code from the [AngularJS docs on select](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select)

if I change this bit of markup

```
<select ng-model="myColor" ng-options="color.name for color in colors">
  <option value="">-- choose color --</option>
</select>
```

To this bit of markup

```
<select ng-model="myColor">
  <option value="">-- choose color --</option>
  <option value="{{idx}}" ng-repeat="(idx, color) in colors">{{color.name}}</option>
</select>
```

The data binding on the middle select stops working. Is there a way to make the data binding work using the ng-repeat and not ng-options?

-- Edit 3 --
This code seems to work...

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', function AppCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.filterCondition = {
    operator: 'eq'
  }

  $scope.operators = [{
    value: 'eq',
    displayName: 'equals',
    title: 'The equals operator does blah, blah'
  }, {
    value: 'neq',
    displayName: 'not equal',
    title: 'The not equals operator does yada yada'
  }]
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
  <div>Operator is: {{filterCondition.operator}}</div>
  <select ng-model="filterCondition.operator">
    <option ng-repeat="operator in operators" title="{{operator.title}}" ng-selected="{{operator.value == filterCondition.operator}}" value="{{operator.value}}">{{operator.displayName}}</option>
  </select>
  <select ng-model="filterCondition.operator">
    <option ng-repeat="operator in operators" title="{{operator.title}}" ng-selected="{{operator.value == filterCondition.operator}}" value="{{operator.value}}">{{operator.displayName}}</option>
  </select>
  <input ng-model="filterCondition.operator">
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Forked your [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/yo9LswNQtcMzDacebAwC?p=preview)

```
<select ng-model="controller.port" required="" class="form-control form-control-inline"  ng-options="item as (item + (c.isPWMUsed(item)?'used' : '')) for item in c.pwm">
                    <option value="">Choose a port</option>
                </select>
```

- I have used ng-value instead of value. Somehow value is not working
- Initial string value in also not working. If you set initial value as string, it is not working. (Don't know why?)
- If you want to use ng-option, then you will not have ng-disabled. But ng-option gives you better support than repeat on option. There are some third party directive which you can use to disable option in ng-option also. Checkout [this](http://jsfiddle.net/alalonde/dZDLg/9/). This is an example to disabled option working with ng-option.

Comment: Does the ng-model binding only work with ng-options? Is there a way to preserve the "disabled" functionality to disallow selection of an already selected number?

Answer (score 0):

@dhavalcengg had one solution however it didn't allow for disabling selected options.

As it turns out I just had to add an ng-selected attribute to the option to force it to select when the predefined value was already set.